# Unable to add widgets to the left side

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I have two buttons here, and I want them to be added to the left corner upon the label which is also on the left. But it always adds buttons on the right side. Here's what I did :

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtGui import QCursor
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QFrame
from PySide2.QtCore import QRect

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(250, 80, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("test app")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #ffffff; border")

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label.setFixedWidth(240)
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(246, 246, 246, 255);")

        profile = QtWidgets.QLabel('Scrappr.io',self)
        profile.move(10, 10)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        right_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

        glay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(right_container)

        glay.setColumnStretch(1, 1)                                     # setColumnStretch
        glay.setRowStretch(1, 1)                                        # setRowStretch
        glay.setRowStretch(2, 2)                                        # setRowStretch
        glay.setRowStretch(3, 1)                                        # setRowStretch

# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button1")
        b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button2")

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(b1)
        vbox.addStretch()
        vbox.addWidget(b2)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        hlay.addWidget(label)
        hlay.addWidget(right_container)
        hlay.addLayout(vbox)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It gives the output, adding the two buttons appear on the right side. I know, it's all because of the horizontal layout.

**What I want to achieve is those buttons on the right side to be on the left side (as I marked):**

[image: Gui app]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding items to a QHBoxLayout it is done from left to right so "vbox" is added to the right side, and "vbox" is the button position handler.

A possible solution is to put the QVBoxLayout "inside" the label and not add it to the QHBoxLayout:

```
# ...
b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button1")
b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button2")

vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(label)
vbox.addWidget(b1)
vbox.addStretch()
vbox.addWidget(b2)

hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
hlay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
hlay.addWidget(label)
hlay.addWidget(right_container)
# hlay.addLayout(vbox) # <--- remove this line
# ...
```

[image]